# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Sentry.captureBreadcrumb')

Tags: react-native, sentry, react-native-sentry

I have upgraded to @sentry/react-native latest version with react-native version 0.62.2.

Already I am using react-native-sentry package with react-native version 0.59.9 it works fine.

After the upgrade, I have changed the import alone and run pod install. After bundle success `evaluating '_reactNative.Sentry.captureBreadcrumb'`. How to fix this?

My question is while upgrading sentry from react-native-sentry to @sentry/react-native and with the latest version of RN (0.62.2) shall I need to a setup wizard as mentioned here `yarn sentry-wizard -i reactNative -p ios android` https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/#linking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That same documentation has a section for upgrading from `react-native-sentry` to `@sentry/react-native`:

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/#upgrading-from-react-native-sentry

Basically first you `react-native unlink react-native-sentry`. Then:

> After that remove react-native-sentry from your package.json:

```
npm uninstall react-native-sentry --save
# or
yarn remove react-native-sentry
```

Once you've done that, just install `@sentry/react-native` as the documentation describes like if it was a new project.

Comment: So here I not needed to setup the wizard while upgrading the existing one. So why the evaluating '_reactNative.Sentry.captureBreadcrumb' error occurs. Already I have run pod install and added the package

Comment: captureBreadcrumb doesn't exist in the new SDK. Please check the docs for the new API: https://docs.sentry.io/enriching-error-data/breadcrumbs/?platform=javascript#recording-crumbs